# Check if an entire row has value 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet "Sheet1"  with the weeknumber in A1.
I have an other sheet "Sheet2" with weeknumbers in column A. Column B to Z contains numbers corresponding to the weeknumbers.

Now I want to check with VBA if the entire row, column B to Z on "Sheet2" contains the value 0 (zero)

How can I do that?

I have this code to select the specific row corresponding to the weeknumber on Sheet 1:

```
Dim WeekNr As Long
WeekNr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(WeekNr + 2, 2)
```

But i don't know how to check if every cell contains a zero from B to Z.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different queries so I am confused. Addressing both...

> i want to check with VBA if the entire row, column B to Z on "Sheet2" contains the value 0 (zero)

**Non VBA Solution**

```
=COUNTIF(B1:Z1,0)>0
```

**VBA Solution**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B1:Z1"), 0) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Found"
Else
    MsgBox "not Found"
End If
```

> But i don't know how to check if every cell contains a zero from B to Z.

**Non VBA Solution**

```
=IF(SUM(B1:Z1)>0,"Not Every Cell has 0","Cell has 0 or blank values")
```

**VBA Solution**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("B1:Z1")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found"
End If
```

**NOTE**: If you only want to check for `0` and not for blank cells then you can use this as well

**Non VBA Solution**

```
=COUNTIF(B1:Z1,0)=25
```

**VBA Solution**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B1:Z1"), 0) = 25 Then
    MsgBox "All cells have 0"
Else
    MsgBox "All cells do not have 0"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! The first VBA solution was the solution for me.

Comment: Awesome. I happen to check your profile. I rarely say this but seems like you are not aware of [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Please note that accepting answers are not mandatory though. The above link is only for your FYI in case you are not aware :)

Answer (score 0):

> Try this to check if value is 0 or not (it will get values from active sheet, you can use any sheet with sheet name according to your requirement)

```
Sub checkzeros()
    Dim weekRange As Range
    Set weekRange = Range("B1:Z1")
    For Each cell In weekRange
        Debug.Print cell.Value
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            ' do what ever yu want if value is 0
        Else
            ' do what ever yu want if value is not 0
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```